# How is the ExecutionContext class related to "contexts"?

Tags: .net, executioncontext

Contexts create subdivided "containers" within domains for objects with special needs (or in the case of objects that don't have special needs, the default context is used).

I am having trouble understanding how the ExecutionContext class relates to these contexts.

How are they related, or different, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

`ExecutionContext` is a container for information related to the execution of a thread. So it's pretty much just a specialized context. It has a few neat properties, but they're likely not applicable to other kinds of contexts, which is okay since different contexts can have different uses.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.executioncontext.aspx):

> The ExecutionContext class provides a
>   single container for all information
>   relevant to a logical thread of
>   execution. This includes security
>   context, call context, and
>   synchronization context.
>
> The ExecutionContext class provides
>   the functionality for user code to
>   capture and transfer this context
>   across user-defined asynchronous
>   points. The common language runtime
>   ensures that the ExecutionContext is
>   consistently transferred across
>   runtime-defined asynchronous points
>   within the managed process.
>
> An execution context is the managed
>   equivalent of a COM apartment. Within
>   an application domain, the entire
>   execution context must be transferred
>   whenever a thread is transferred. This
>   situation occurs during transfers made
>   by the Thread.Start method, most
>   thread pool operations, and Windows
>   Forms thread marshaling through the
>   Windows message pump. It does not
>   occur in unsafe thread pool operations
>   (such as the UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem
>   method), which do not transfer the
>   compressed stack.

You can find out more information about the ExecutionContext at the link above.